# Restore backed up volume to another docker container (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, bash, docker, docker-compose

I have backed postgres volume using this command:

```bash
sudo docker run --rm --volumes-from base -v $(pwd):/docker-volumes ubuntu tar cvf /docker-volumes/base_data.tar /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

It worked and then I transferred the `.tar` file to another server using `scp`.
Now I need the postgres container in the new server to restore this data.

- The new container is running and called `base`.
- `~/docker-volumes/base_data.tar` is where the backup file in the server.
- `/var/lib/posgresql/data` is where this `.tar` must be unpacked inside the container.

I tried this:

```bash
sudo docker run --rm --volumes-from base -v $(pwd):/docker-volumes ubuntu bash -c "cd /var/lib/postgresql/data && tar xvf /docker-volumes/base_data.tar --strip 1"
```

I tried to tweek it in multiple ways but didnt work.

Comment: Maybe you don't need to `cd /var/lib/postgresql/data` before `tar xvzf` because the original dir tree is preserved in the tarfile?

Comment: Please describe what went wrong.  "Didn't work" is not a suitable description.

Comment: A backup taken just with `tar` is likely to be corrupt unless the database was in the shutdown state while it was taken.  It is best to use pg_basebackup.